# Cloud Functions-TypeScript- "Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)"

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

This is my code:

```
export const newPost = functions.firestore
.document('post/{postId}/')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const postData = snap.data()
    const authorId = postData.uid    
});
```

I get the error that postData is possibly undefined, the way around this is to check if postData != null and then inside {} use postData object.

This is the code from documentation:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // Get an object representing the document
  // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
  const newValue = snap.data();

  // access a particular field as you would any JS property
  const name = newValue.name;

  // perform desired operations ...
});
```

It is not mentioned here that there could be undefined object newValue, also by reading many examples of cloud functions with firestore I haven't seen that people would check if .data() != null before using it

Comment: In general the `DataSnapshot.data()` method can return `null` or `undefined`. Although that may not be the case in your situation, the compiler/linter is apparently not able to figure that out.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what do you recommend we do? I'm in a simirlar situation. I already added a conditional but still, the linter is complaining. Should I update the tslint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TypeScript configuration almost certainly has strict type checking enabled, which will give you this warning when you try to access properties of something that could be null or undefined.  Check your tsconfig.json and look for `"strict": true"` in the compiler options.  The TypeScript bindings for the [DataSnapshot.data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) API says that the return value of data() could anything (including null or undefined), and TypeScript is forcing you to deal with this fact correctly at compile time so that your code doesn't crash at runtime.

The sample code you're looking at is plain JavaScript, which does not have any type checking.  It is assuming that the snapshot will not be null or undefined.  If you found this to be confusing or problematic, please use the "send feedback" link at the top of the page of documentation to explain what was confusing to you.

Comment: Disabling strict checking can lead to run-time errors if the data is actually undefined or null, right?

Comment: @Abhi Strict mode has no bearing on what happens at runtime.  It's a compiler setting.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but a quick fix `const postData: any = snap.data()`